# Действия для получения знака «Дисциплинированный»

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Описание знака [«Дисциплинированный»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) гласит:

> Удалить свое сообщение с рейтингом минимум 3 балла.

Для чего может понадобиться его удалять? Ведь если сообщение заплюсовали, значит, оно полезное/помогло/правильное.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Заплюсованный ответ может стать устаревшим с развитием языков и программных сред, так что удаление порой имеет смысл.

Не все знаки предназначены для того, чтобы к ним намеренно стремились. Некоторые из них больше похожи на утешительные призы: бродяга, скрытый талант, непризнанный гений. Этот можно отнести к тому же разряду.